# Does/can a modern indirect tanked hot water system draw heat on-demand to keep itself full of hot water?

Tags: hot-water, central-heating

In my previous experience with old tanked systems they simply ran on a timer so if you used all the hot water you had to manually boost it to get some more.

Using modern boilers and unvented hot water tank systems, is this still typical or can you simply tell the water tank what temperature you want and it will draw heat on-demand from the boiler, topping itself back up every time you run a bath/shower?

If so does this have any particular name/technology I can read up on and is it the standard approach or something I would need to specifically request when getting quotes for a new system?

Comment: I think you meant a thermostat instead of a timer.   Most systems that heat water work to keep the water at a certain temperature, either to maintain the temperature in a tank if water is not used, or to heat up the colder water that comes in during use.

Comment: @crip659 no I don't. My past experience of older tanked systems is they heat up overnight and if you use all the hot water there is none left until next night, or you override the control. (Obviously there _is_ a thermostat so the heating doesn't overshoot as well)

Comment: I have had tanked systems for fifty plus years, none had a timer.  Do imagine some places might only have cheap power cost over night and a timer might be useful to save money, but think that be more of the exception than general use.

Comment: It was certainly the norm in the UK that both hot water tank and heating generally would have timers when I was growing up, we had a dual tariff quite commonly. It's interesting how you keep finding locale-specific things on what you might think would be universal based on the science :)